# Select2 custom message formatting

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

I am using [Select2 Version 3.5.2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) and need to trigger a custom message if my AJAX result length is greater than *x*. How can you trigger a custom message which I can handle in the same way like given messages formatting messages (formatLoadMore, formatSelectionTooBig, ...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override *formatResult* and implement a custom behaviour. Eg. for a special property in your resultset (**result.error**):

```
function formatResult(result, container, query, escapeMarkup) {
   var markup = [];
   if(result.error != undefined && result.error) {
      markError(result.text, markup);
   } else {
      Select2.util.markMatch(result.text, query.term, markup, escapeMarkup);
   }
   return markup.join("");
};
```

special format:

```
function markError(text, markup) {
   markup.push("<b style='color: red;'>");
   markup.push(text);
   markup.push("</b>")
};
```